# Does iTunes Match renewals use Gift Card credit?

Tags: itunes, itunes-match, gift

My iTunes Match account is due for renewal, and I have some money credited to my account. I would prefer to have iTunes just credit my card versus using this gift card. When I look this up online, a lot of people reference that it does charge the card, but requires you to have another payment option.

This is always a confusing space. For example, I know you can't gift an app to someone with GC credit.

My question is, if I have any credit in my account, is it going to take that first, or can I have it just use the CC?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can!

According to http://support.apple.com/en-us/ht4914:

"You can use store credit to pay for your iTunes Match subscription; however, you must have a valid payment method on file at the time of sign up."

Comment: revised my question to make it more clear, I am wondering if it does that, is there a way around it.